# Disable Data Integrity Step in Migration

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

I got below error while I am trying to Migrate from Magento1 to Magento2.

> Foreign key (FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 121,163,164 from `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`

I would not like to delete records from Magento 1 database.

I got to keep the records, disable the Data Integrity Step by modifying the Data Migration Tool’s `config.xml`. in [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-troubleshooting.html?fbclid=IwAR0f00ENXdYXuOzxx89xP2Bkaxz5KWXTlRfdvGcVL4_2lsbAVAaQckXbqfU) link to solve this error.

How can I disable the Data Integrity Step?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `config.xml` and comment below line,

```
<step title="Data Integrity Step">
    <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
</step>
```